# Clicking button should open .container3

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

If there is any more information you need, please let me know.

I don't know why this is so hard for me to figure out.

I am able to get from `.container1`. to `.container2` from the **1st** exit button, but I can't seem to get from `.container2` to `.container3` from the other, **2nd** exit button.

When viewing the code example I provided, scroll down to see the exit button.

The problem that I am having is that, clicking on the **2nd** exit button should take me to `.container3`.

The **2nd** exit button appears after clicking on the **1st** exit button.

Small Reproducible Code: https://jsfiddle.net/reuqancf/

Full Code I am working on: https://jsfiddle.net/pzn98Lw6/

Here is a demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/h5vkt3br/

You can see how it works in there.

Look closely at the **demo code** to see how that one is set up.

What is supposed to occur in the code I am working on is, after clicking on the **2nd** exit button it's supposed to take me to `.container3` and it is not doing that.

Clicking on the exit button initiates the `"initial-fade"` after clicking the exit button the **1st** time.

```
body.initial-fade {
  animation: initial-fade 1s ease forwards;
}
```

When I **click** on the **2nd** exit button, nothing is occurring.

Nothing is happening when I click on the **2nd** exit button.

Why is nothing occurring, and how is that fixed so that, clicking on the **2nd** exit button takes you to `.container3`?

How am I able to exit `.container2`,

The same way I was able to exit `.container1`?

In the **demo code** I provided: Two of these were used:

I am currently only using **1**.

If I am needing another one of these, how would it be added to the code?

```
function animationEndHandler(evt) {
    const animationName = evt.animationName;

    if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
        body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
        showCover(currentPlayButton);
    }
}

body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler);

function animationEndHandler(evt) {

    const animationName = evt.animationName;
    console.log(animationName);

    if (animationName === "fadingOut") {
        fadeReset();
    }
}

body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler);

/*.fadingOut .isOpen*/
.fadingOut .outer {
  animation: fadingOut 1s ease;
  animation-delay: 11.3s;
}
```

**Small Reproducible Code:** Of the code that is being worked on.

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function showCover(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
  }

  function openCurtain(curtain) {
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCover(cover);
    const curtain = evt.currentTarget.parentElement
    .parentElement.parentElement;
    openCurtain(curtain);
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

   function init(/*selectors*/ ) {
  //config.containers = document.querySelector(selectors.container);
 // const allContainers = document.querySelector(".container");
  //const playButtons = document.querySelector(selectors.playButton);
  const allPlaybuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
  //const allPlaybuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".embed-youtube-play");
  addClickToButtons( allPlaybuttons);
   }
  

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
   init
  };
}());

const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {
const body = document.body;

    const players = [];

  function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": allWrappers[index]
      });
    });
  }

  // inline arrow function, direct return
  function getWrapper(cover) {
    const index = players.findIndex(
      (player) => player.cover === cover
    );
    return players[index].wrapper;
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const background = document.querySelector(backgroundSelector);
    background.classList.add("bg1");
  }

  function animationEndHandler(evt) {
    const animationName = evt.animationName;
   // console.log(animationName);
    if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
      body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
      resetPage();
    }
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
  }

  function exitClickHandler() {
    body.classList.add('initial-fade');
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addExitHandlers(callback) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", callback);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    findPlayers();
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
    body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler);
  }

  return {
    addExitHandlers,
    getWrapper,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let player;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    //player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    //shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }


  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {

  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    // enablejsapi: 1,
    //loop: 1,
    //playlist: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };

  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

   function playerAdder(wrapper, playerOptions) {
        return function addPlayerCallback() {
            initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
        };
    }
  function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    delete wrapper.player;
  }

  function removePlayerHandler(/*evt*/) {
    //const el = evt.target;
    //const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrap");
    if (wrapper.player) {
      return removePlayer(wrapper);
    }
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    removePlayerHandler
  };
}());

const players = (function coverUIPlayerFacade() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    const wrapper = manageUI.getWrapper(cover);
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(wrapper, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }


  function init() {
    manageCover.init({
      //container: ".container",
      playButton: ".cover"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
    manageUI.addExitHandlers(managePlayer.removePlayerHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

players.init();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  players.add(".playa", {
    playerVars: {
      loop: 1,
      playlist: "djV11Xbc914"
    }
  });
  players.add(".playb", {});
  players.add(".playc", {});
  players.add(".playd", {});
  players.add(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: ["mnfmQe8Mv1g", "M7lc1UVf-VE",
        "-Xgi_way56U", "CHahce95B1g"
      ]
    }
  });
  players.add(".playf", {});
   players.add(".playg", {});
  players.add(".playh", {});
  players.add(".playi", {});
  players.add(".playj", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: ["mnfmQe8Mv1g", "M7lc1UVf-VE",
        "-Xgi_way56U", "CHahce95B1g"
      ]
    }
  });
  players.add(".playk", {});
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  background: #302b63;
}

.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

body.initial-fade {
  animation: initial-fade 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes initial-fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: bg1 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes bg1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background: teal;
  }
}

body.bg2 {
  animation: bg2 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes bg2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background: teal;
  }
}


.container2 {
  display: none;
}
.container3 {
  display: none;
}
.bg1 .container1 {
  display: none;
}
.bg1 .container2 {
  display: flex;
}
.bg2 .container2 {
  display: none;
}
.bg2 .container3 {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}


.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1 ">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="wrap embed-youtube ">
      <div class="video embed-youtube  " data-id="djV11Xbc914">
      </div>
      <button class="playa cover playgreen  embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playb cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playc cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playd cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playe cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playf cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playg cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playh cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playi cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playj cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playk cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways to fix the issues with this, so I'll mainly point out what the problems are, and show you 1 way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Looking at your css it seems like the class .bg2 is what you want to display the div with the class .container3.

Your css:

```
    .bg2 .container3 {
      display: flex;
    }
```

Now you need css to hide the div's with the classes .container1, and .container2 when that .bg2 class gets applied.

```
    .bg2 .container1, .bg2 .container2 {
      display: none;
    }
```

**Now the JS**
Your js that adds the class of .bg1 only gets ran once when the js is initialized. That's why your class of .bg2 is not getting added. If you want to continue to solve the problem via this path, I would suggest moving the call to resetPage() (which is currently in the animationEndHandler() function), to the exitClickHandler() function. That way it will get called every time the exit button is clicked.

```
    function animationEndHandler(evt) {
      const animationName = evt.animationName;
      console.log(animationName);
      if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
        body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
        // moving this to exitClickHandler()
        // resetPage();
      }
    }
 
    function exitClickHandler() {
      body.classList.add('initial-fade');
      resetPage();
    }
```

There's one more change to make. I did this a quick way because I'm not sure how you'd like to handle the displaying of your containers.

In the resetBackground() function I stated above it's only adding the class of bg1 to your body tag. We need to modify this because in your css you have a class of bg2 which hides the other 2 containers and shows the third container. I created a counter variable and set it to 1 because your first class to add is bg1. Then I increment the counter after bg1 is added to your body tag. So next time the class added to your body tag is bg2.

```
    let counter = 1;
    function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
      const background = document.querySelector(backgroundSelector);
      background.classList.add("bg" + counter);
      counter++;
    }
```

Again, there's multiple ways to accomplish the hiding and displaying of your containers of videos. Hope this helps you.

Here is a link to a working jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/rpb138/xvr2uzse/3/

Comment: Can you show me it working in a jsfiddle link?

Comment: What are the other ways that would resolve or fix the issue?

Comment: It all depends on what your plan for the UI is. Try to make it as easy as possible for your audience to use this. It's seems a little strange to me that when you click the exit button, a new set of videos is displayed. I'm not sure what your end result is supposed to be. The original demo you posted has a grid of 9 videos that open one at a time, & then you close that video to go back to the grid. That's what the js was original meant for. Instead of clicking on the exit button to move to the next group of videos maybe consider having pagination where each group is shown by clicking on a page.